# I want to upload a XML file from a form page. After the upload, the values of the xml file had to be put in my array

Tags: php, xml, arrays

Below you can see my formpage, at this page you upload a xml file.

```
<html>
<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="arrayincludefiletest.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
<table width="600">
<tr>
<td>File name:</td>
<td><input type="file" name="file" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Below you can see my PHP code, if you take a look you can see that now everything is manual. I have to fill the array by myself. But I want that the array will be fill automatic by the values of the XML File. So if you upload a XML File the values of the file will automatically fill my array. Also you can see that I insert the array into my database.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Bom Array </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$bom= array(
        array("Aantal" =>1, "Manufactorer" =>"Panasonic", "Partno" =>"EEEFC1H1R0R", 
                "Description" =>"Capacitor 0603","Footprint" =>"CAP0603", "Refdes" =>"B1"),
        array("Aantal" =>2, "Manufactorer" =>"Vishay", "Partno" =>"MAL215371228E3", 
                "Description" =>"Capacitor 1210","Footprint" =>"CAP1210", "Refdes" =>"C6,C7"),
        array("Aantal" =>3, "Manufactorer" =>"Ferroxcube", "Partno" =>"MAL215371109E3", 
                "Description" =>"Buzzer 80dB 3,4 KHz","Footprint" =>"KPEG238", "Refdes" =>"C8,C25"),
        array("Aantal" =>4, "Manufactorer" =>"Philips", "Partno" =>"EEEFC1E101P", 
                "Description" =>"Tantaal 100uF, 6,3V Case_B","Footprint" =>"Case_B", "Refdes" =>"C1")
);

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>
        <th>Aantal</th>
        <th>Manufactorer</th>
        <th>Partno</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Footprint</th>
        <th>Refdes</th>
     </tr>";

echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $bom[0]['Aantal'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[0]['Manufactorer'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[0]['Partno'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[0]['Description'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[0]['Footprint'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[0]['Refdes'] . "</td>
      </tr>";

echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $bom[1]['Aantal'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[1]['Manufactorer'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[1]['Partno'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[1]['Description'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[1]['Footprint'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[1]['Refdes'] . "</td>
      </tr>";

echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $bom[2]['Aantal'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[2]['Manufactorer'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[2]['Partno'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[2]['Description'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[2]['Footprint'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[2]['Refdes'] . "</td>
      </tr>";

echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $bom[3]['Aantal'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[3]['Manufactorer'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[3]['Partno'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[3]['Description'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[3]['Footprint'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $bom[3]['Refdes'] . "</td>
      </tr>";
echo "</table>";

// Connectie database and Insert into database
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "csa", "csa", "csa");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(is_array($bom))
{
    $sql= "INSERT INTO bom (Aantal, Manufactorer, Partno, Description, Footprint, Refdes) values";

    $valuesArr = array();
    foreach ($bom as $row)
    {   
        $aantal = (int) $row['Aantal'];
        $manufactorer = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['Manufactorer']);
        $partno = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['Partno']);
        $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['Description']);
        $footprint = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['Footprint']);
        $refdes = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['Refdes']);

        $valuesArr[] = "('$aantal', '$manufactorer', '$partno', '$description', '$footprint', '$refdes')";
    }

    $sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);
    mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('Error:' . mysqli_errno($con));

}

mysqli_close($con);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP SimpleXML extension to read XML files and convert them to objects. If you run PHP 5.1.2 or later, it is enabled by default.
The PHP manual provides some excellent examples.

**Step 1: saving the XML file**

The first thing to decide is whether you want to store the XML files. In that case, have a look at the "POST method upload" example (http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). If you want to move the uploaded XML file to a directory named "xml" inside your current folder, it would look like this:

```
if(!empty($_FILES)) {
    $uploaddir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/xml/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo 'The XML file has been successfully uploaded.';
    } else {
        echo 'Error occurred while saving the uploaded file.';
    }
}
```

**Step 2: reading the XML file**

The next step is to load the XML file using SimpleXML and convert it to an object (see examples at http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). First you need to define an XML structure for your data. For example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<boms>
    <bom>
            <aantal>1</aantal>
            <manufactorer>Panasonic</manufactorer>
            <partno>EEEFC1H1R0R</partno>
            <description>Capacitor 0603</description>
            <footprint>CAP0603</footprint>
            <refdes>B1</refdes>
    </bom>
    <bom>
            <aantal>2</aantal>
            <manufactorer>Vishay</manufactorer>
            <partno>MAL215371228E3</partno>
            <description>Capacitor 1210</description>
            <footprint>CAP1210</footprint>
            <refdes>C6,C7</refdes>
    </bom>
</boms>
```

Then to read the XML file and loop through the rows to echo them or save them to the database:

```
if(isset($uploadfile) && file_exists($uploadfile)) {
    $bom = simplexml_load_file($uploadfile);
    if(!$bom) {
        die('Unable to load XML file.');
    }

    foreach($bom as $row) {
        echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $row->aantal . "</td>
        <td>" . $row->manufactorer . "</td>
        <td>" . $row->partno . "</td>
        <td>" . $row->description . "</td>
        <td>" . $row->footprint . "</td>
        <td>" . $row->refdes . "</td>
      </tr>";
    }
}
```

A few notes on these examples:

- There is no validation as to whether the uploaded file actually is an XML file and if it has the structure you defined. Make sure you check that before parsing it.
- The "xml" directory has to be writable by your webserver.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I have to make a new file or do I have to just paste this examples that you give me. If I just have to paste them, after which code do I have to paste the examples that you give to me.

Comment: I see this post is a copy of your previous post - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113642/i-want-to-upload-a-file-and-when-the-file-upload-the-values-of-the-file-has-to) - where someone else has already tried to help you. Have you tried experimenting with the examples given?